How to convert the plotly expandable sparkline example from the bslib docs to a Highcharter plot?
bslib has helpful documentation around their expandable sparklines. The documentation uses javascript to modify an existing plotly plot when a card is expanded. I'm trying to mimic the same behavior but for a highcharter plot instead of a plotly plot.
I want this to be in javascript, and not use shiny::getCurrentOutputInfo() as it creates a lag when expanding and minimizing the window.
I'd like the plot to have both x and y axes visible as well as the plot to be exportable when expanded and hide those elements when minimized. This is essentially the behavior I'd like to see using the getCurrentOutputInfo function (notice the lag and re-rendering of the plot).
Example App
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(highcharter)

ui <- page_fluid(
    value_box(
      title = "Test",
      value = "Test",
      showcase = highchartOutput("hcp"),
      showcase_layout = showcase_top_right(),
      full_screen = TRUE,
      theme = "success"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                   len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))
  
  output$hcp <- renderHighchart({
    highchart_scatter()
  })
  
  highchart_scatter <- function(x) {
    info <- getCurrentOutputInfo()
    large <- isTRUE(info$height() > 200)
    
    df2 <- df %>% 
      hchart('line', hcaes(x = dose, y = len))
    
    if(large){
      df2 <- df2 %>%
        hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
    } else {
      df2 <- df2 %>%
        hc_xAxis(visible = FALSE) %>% 
        hc_yAxis(visible = FALSE)
    }
    return(df2)
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

And this is the sample js code for reformating a plotly plot that I'd essentially like to mimic.
plotly javascript example
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    "function(el) {
      var ro = new ResizeObserver(function() {
         var visible = el.offsetHeight > 200;
         Plotly.relayout(el, {'xaxis.visible': visible});
      });
      ro.observe(el);
    }"
  )


Using js, you could do it like this:
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(highcharter)

ui <- page_fluid(
  value_box(
    title = "Test",
    value = "Test",
    showcase = highchartOutput("hcp"),
    showcase_layout = showcase_top_right(),
    full_screen = TRUE,
    theme = "success"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                   len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))
  
  output$hcp <- renderHighchart({
    highchart_scatter() |> 
      htmlwidgets::onRender("function(el, x) {
                              var ro = new ResizeObserver(function() {
                                var visible = el.offsetHeight > 200;
                                var chart = $('#' + el.id).highcharts()
                              
                                chart.xAxis[0].update({
                                  visible: visible
                                })
                              
                                chart.yAxis[0].update({
                                  visible: visible
                                })

                                chart.exporting.update({
                                  enabled: visible
                                })
                              });
                              ro.observe(el);
                            }")
  })
  
  highchart_scatter <- function(x) {
    
    df2 <- df %>% 
      hchart('line', hcaes(x = dose, y = len))

    return(df2)
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)



Fantastic! Is there a way to add the exporting features as well?

Ah, I hope so ... Can you clarify what you mean by exporting features? What is your goal and what shall be implemented, do you have an example somewhere?

The example R code above uses the R function hc_exporting which provides the user the option to download the source data in .csv or export the plot, the API reference is here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.

I tried adding chart.exporting[0].update({enabled: true}), didn't seem to work, but my js knowledge is very limited.

You nearly have it. Drop the [0] and it should work. Please see my updated answer and tell me, whether it is suitable.

Perfect! As a js newbie, what is the [0] doing for the x and y axis?

xAxis and yAxis are arrays, and with [0] you access the first element of this array. Imagine the case that you have multiple axes, then you may want to apply certain behavior only to some axes. The API says: "In case of multiple axes, the xAxis node is an array of configuration objects.".
